# delete duplicates in Vector of data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, vector, duplicates

I have a `Vector`, each cell is containing a `Data Structure` :

```
public class objet_poid_n {
   public  int Num;
    public double Poid;
}
```

The problem is that the Vector may have duplications and i need to create a function or procedure able to delete duplicates .. 
I tried this one and it couldn't help ..

```
 public static void removeDuplicates(Vector v)
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<v.size();j++)
                {
                    if(i!=j)
                        {
                            if(v.elementAt(i).equals(v.elementAt(j)))
                                {
                                    v.removeElementAt(j);
                                }
                        }
                }
                                   }
}
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: _I tried this one and it couldn't help_ Why? What happened?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, i mean it gives me some duplicates elements ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should implement an `equals()` method in your `objet_poid_n` because the [default behavior compares memory addresses.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277813/the-behaviour-of-equals-method-in-java)

Then you could either use the method [Vector.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) before inserting a new object in your vector or use a `Set` which is by definition a collection without duplicates.

Comment: `public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
 return (this == obj);
}`

Then you mean i use a loop to compare ìf(Vector.contains(newitem) == true) Vector.add(newitem)` ??

Comment: `public boolean equals(objet_poid_n obj) 
{
    if((obj.Num == this.Num) && (obj.Poid == this.Poid))
            return true;
                    else
 return (false);
}`

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk

Comment: Logically what you say and what you have mentioned is logical and it should do remove duplicates ! and i think that the problem is in the code later . i will mention your answer as a correct answer as a solution for resolving the Duplications of a Data structure Vector and i will check my code maybe the error is not there :)

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about how to remove duplicates, always first consider a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). By definition, a `Set` is

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Iterate over your array and add them to a `Set` implementation. Use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if order is important.

The elements in the `Set` will be unique. You can add them back to your a new `List` or `clear()` the old one and add them there.

**Note:** You should implement a `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` method in your `objet_poid_n` class.

**Note2:** If by `Vector` you mean `java.util.Vector`, please don't use it. Use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements in your arrays will change the size and you will try to access indices that no longer exist.

The simplest solution is:

1. Implements `hashcode`/`equals` in your `objet_poid_n`
2. Add all your elements in a `HashSet`

Then your `Set` will contain only one instance of each element.

Read about `hashcode`/`equals` and `HashSet` if necessary. It is worth your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to remove dulplicate elements from vector

public static Vector removeDuplicateResults(Vector resultsVector)
    {

```
    for(int i=0;i<resultsVector.size();i++){        
        for(int j=0;j<resultsVector.size();j++){            
                if(i!=j){                                            
                    Object resultsVectorObject1 = resultsVector.elementAt(i);
                    Object resultsVectorObject2 = resultsVector.elementAt(j);
                    Object[] resultsObjectArray1 = (Object[]) resultsVectorObject1;
                    Object[] resultsObjectArray2 = (Object[]) resultsVectorObject2;
                    if(Arrays.equals(resultsObjectArray1, resultsObjectArray2))
                    {
                        resultsVector.removeElementAt(j);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return resultsVector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the add or addAll methods in my case I used data as a local variable:

```
data = new Vector<String>() {
        @Override
        public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vector<String> v = (Vector<String>) arg0;
            for (String string : v) {
                if (contains(string)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return super.addAll(v);
        }
    };
```